# How to iterate over a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Say we got a tensor like this`x = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]`. I want a tensorflow operation such that it returns adding 1 to every element of first nested tensor. i.e. the result the operation will return `[[[2,3],[3,4]],[[6,7],[7,8]]]`.
I know the `tf.map_fn` operation, but I don't find a way to implement using this operation. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the tensor at the first axis, add one to the first tensors in the first axis and then stack the new and old tensors using `tf.stack`:

```
>>> x = tf.constant([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],[[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
...    sess.run(tf.stack((x[:,0] + 1, x[:, 1]), axis=1))
... 
array([[[2, 3],
        [3, 4]],

       [[6, 7],
        [7, 8]]], dtype=int32)
```